# How to install PHP on Tomcat webserver?

Tags: php, tomcat6

I would like to run both JSP and PHP webpages from Tomcat server. I googled and tried to follows those steps but no luck.

I would like to install PHP on Apache Tomcat > 6.0 . Can anyone guide me to configure ?

Serenity

Comment: I think this question belongs to [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/). And can you please provide what you have tried and what exactly is not working?

Comment: I copied and updated the properties from php5srvlt.jar (Downloaded PECL 5.2.5 Win32 binaries) and also copied the 3 jar file's to Tomcat/llib directory and modified the web.xml file. After making the changes, it either says "Wrapper cannot find servlet class net.php.servlet" or "Servlet php is not available". I referred the following weblinks : http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/tomcat6.php

Comment: Hmm can you edit your question and add the parts of your web.xml which you have added? I'm not sure but I think the names have to be correct - the classname is `php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet` and does not begin with `net.` - perhaps that is the problem (same with the servlet name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/servlet-programming.php

key point

1. You should install php5-cgi.
2. The `JavaBridge.war` and related jar in here
   https://sourceforge.net/projects/php-java-bridge/files/Binary%20package/php-java-bridge_6.2.1/php-java-bridge_6.2.1_documentation.zip